# How do I calculate value of constant C, so that complex function $f(z)=u+j\cdot v$ satisfies condition $f(0)=1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

So I have one harmonic holomorphic function f with $\text{Re}\,=u(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$. So conjugate complex $v(x,y)=-y^3+3x^2+C$.

How do I calculate value of constant $C$, so that complex function $f(z)=u+j\cdot v$ satisfies condition $f(0)=1$?

$$f(z)=u+j\cdot v=x^3-3xy^2+j(-y^3+3x^2+C)$$

$$f(0,0)=0-0+j(0+C)$$

$$jC=1$$

So is answer $j^{-1}$? In my solution is written $-i$? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $j^{-1} = -j$. To check that: $j \cdot (-j) = - j\cdot j = -(-1) = 1$.

More generally, taking integer powers of $j$ just gives these 4 values: $$j^n = \begin{cases} 1 & j \equiv 0 \bmod 4\\j & j \equiv 1 \bmod 4\\-1 & j \equiv 2 \bmod 4\\-j & j \equiv 3 \bmod 4\end{cases}$$